# Maven repository for IBM RTC build toolkit jars

Tags: maven, ant, ibm-rational

I am building custom Ant tasks in Eclipse for Rational Team Concert ant builds. I have the build toolkit in my development environment and I'm using Maven as my build tool.

I really don't want to add the toolkit jar files to my repository;
How would you store such an artifact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those jars are part of their "[All downloads](https://jazz.net/downloads/rational-team-concert/releases/5.0.1?p=allDownloads)" pages, so:

If you don't want to store that jar in a dedicated artifact in your local Nexus referential, you can at least store the url from which you can re-download that jar if/when needed.
That url can be stored in any text file you want, said text file being versioned like any other source file of your project.

It is a declarative approach, one where you declared what you use (a bit like a `pom.xml` declared the dependencies it needs)

Comment: Would eclipse be able to resolve imports if I did this? I suspect not but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @mister270 no it wouldn't: you would need a dedicated script to use that declaration and download the resource.